# Select all rows from Numpy array where each column satisfies some condition

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have an array `x` of the form,

```
x = [[1,2,3,...,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,...,7,9,8],
...,
[9,8,7,...,3,1,2],
[9,8,7,...,3,2,1]]
```

I also have an array of *non-allowed* numbers for each column. I want to select all of the rows which only have allowed characters in each column. For instance, I might have that I want only rows which do not have any of `[1,2,3]` in the first column; I can do this by,

```
x[~np.in1d(x[:,0], [1,2,3])]
```

And for any *single* column, I can do this. But I'm looking to essentially do this for *all* columns at once, selecting only the rows for which every elemnt is an allowed number for its column. I can't seem to get `x.any` or `x.all` to do this well - how should I go about this?

**EDIT**: To clarify, the *non-allowed* numbers are different for each column. In actuality, I will have some array y,

```
y = [[1,4,...,7,8],
[2,5,...,9,4],
[3,6,...,8,6]]
```

Where I want rows from `x` for which column 1 cannot be in `[1,2,3]`, column 2 cannot be in `[4,5,6]`, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [broadcast](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast.html) the comparison, then `all` to check:

```
x[(x != y[:,None,:]).all(axis=(0,-1))]
```

Break down:

```
# compare each element of `x` to each element of `y`
# mask.shape == (y.shape[0], x.shape[0], x.shape[1])
mask = (x != y[:,None,:])

# `all(0)` checks, for each element in `x`, it doesn't match any element in the same column of `y`
# `all(-1) checks along the rows of `x`
mask = mask.all(axis=(0,-1)

# slice
x[mask]
```

For example, consider:

```
x = np. array([[1, 2],
       [9, 8],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])

y = np.array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 7]])
```

Then `mask = (x != y[:,None,:]).all(axis=(0,1))` gives

```
array([False,  True,  True,  True])
```

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more? What is y here, and what exactly is this line doing?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how to implement this for my use. I should have been more explicit - the *disallowed numbers* are different for each column - I might not want [1,2,3] in column 1, but then not want [4,5,8] in column 2. Will this still work for that?

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to use `np.isin` rather than `np.in1d` these days. This lets you (a) compare the entire array all at once, and (b) invert the mask more efficiently.

```
x[np.isin(x, [1, 2, 3], invert=True).all(1)]
```

`np.isin` preserves the shape of `x`, so you can then use `.all` across the columns. It also has an `invert` argument which allows you to do the equivalent of `~isin(x, [1, 2, 3])`, but more efficiently.

This solution vectorizes a similar computation to what the other is suggesting much more efficiently (although it's still a linear search), and avoids creating the temporary arrays as well.